# Can this space be homotopy dominated by $\mathbb{RP}^n\times \mathbb{RP}^m$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

A space $X$ is homotopy dominated by a space $Y$ if there are continuous maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ such that $gf\simeq id_X$.

Let $P$ be a finite polyhedron such that $\pi_1 (P)= \mathbb{Z}_2$  and $\tilde{P}=S^n \times S^m$ for some $n,m\geq 2$. Can this space be homotopy dominated by $\mathbb{RP}^n\times \mathbb{RP}^m$?

Here $\tilde{X}$ denotes the universal covering space of $X$.

Comment: 1. is impossible.

Comment: Maybe in 1 you meant to write $\pi_1(P_1)=\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: If that is what you meant, then the answer to 1 is yes. Also, in either case if the answer is yes then there is the stronger statement that $X$ is homotopy equivalent, not just homotopy dominated, by the sphere or product of spheres.

Comment: @DaveBenson Could you please tell my it is impossible?

Comment: The cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ is not periodic.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie No, I meant $\pi_1 (P_1)=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. If $\pi_1 (P_1)=\mathbb{Z}_2 $, then we can imply that $P_1 \simeq \mathbb{RP}^n$.

Comment: @DaveBenson How can I use your statement to show that $P_1$ is not homotopy dominated by $\mathbb{RP}^n\times \mathbb{RP}^m$? Could you please explain me?

Comment: I'm not saying that. I'm saying that such a $P_1$ does not exist.

Comment: @DaveBenson sorry, I got it now. It means that if $P$ is a polyhedron with $\tilde{P}=S^n$, then the cohomology of its fundamental groups is periodic. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{RP}^n\times S^m$ is not homotopy dominated by $\mathbb{RP}^n\times\mathbb{RP}^m$ when $n$ is odd and $m$ is even, by looking at integral homology in degree $m+n$.

Comment: Dear @MarkGrant , Thanks very much for your answer. That's right but how can I prove that $P$ in the question is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{RP}^n\times S^m$?

Comment: @M.Ramana The conditions on $P$ in the question do not uniquely determine its homotopy type. I can take the quotient of $S^n\times S^m$ by the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on either factor, or the diagonal action, to get an example of such a $P$. I was simply giving an example of a $P$ which is not homotopy dominated by $\mathbb{RP}^n\times\mathbb{RP}^m$.